# Foreach Loop only executing once when called with Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to loop through a textarea array ($taskLinks) with PHP and check each new line entry against the database for matches and return the matches ($a) from the database:

```
    $a = array();
    $array = split("\r\n", $taskLinks);
    foreach($array as $url){
    $query = "SELECT url FROM links
    WHERE  `url` 
    LIKE  '$url'
    AND `projectId` = '$projectId'";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_object ($result);
    $matchedLink = $row->url;
    array_push ($a,$matchedLink);
    }
    foreach ($a as $row){
        echo "$row\r";
    }
```

The PHP script (called linkchecker.php) above works perfectly but im trying to call it with AJAX when the user adds to the textarea and then returns any matches from the above. To do this I have the below, combined with onChange="ajaxFunction()" on the textarea.

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
                ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        var taskLinks = document.getElementById('taskLinks').value;
        <!--
        <?php 
        echo("var projectId = ('$projectId');");
        ?>
        // -->
        var queryString = "?taskLinks=" + taskLinks + "&projectId=" + projectId;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "linkchecker.php" + queryString, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    }
```

The problem is the php script only seems to work when one line is added to the textarea - the variables are passing to the script in the query string and the PHP script works but only for one  line in the textarea - I need it to work for for multiple lines like it does normally.

What can I do to the AJAX to make sure the PHP script checks every entry in the textarea?

Comment: You can create a function that loops through each line in the textarea and passes that data to the PHP script and executes a desired function based off of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the \r is lost when working with values of textarea's, so your pattern `"\r\n"` does not match.
You may use :

```
$array = split("[\r\n]+", $taskLinks);
```

...instead.

Or use e.g. jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (if possible), it keeps the \r

If you cannot use jQuery you also may use jQuery's approach to keep the \r .
It replaces inside strings occurencies  of `/\r?\n/g` with `"\r\n"`

**EDIT:**

---

you also need to encode the parameters:

```
var queryString = "?taskLinks=" + encodeURIComponent(taskLinks) + 
                  "&projectId=" + encodeURIComponent(projectId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately no luck editing the php pattern. I think the real issue is in the AJAX, the PHP does work fine when its done on the same page.